# SEO - Do symbols affect keywords?

Tags: seo

Will any of the following keywords, with the registered mark, have any affect when `Company Name` is being searched, or do symbols and tags play no role?

1. `Company Name` (obviously no affect)
2. `Company Name®`
3. `Company Name&reg;`
4. `Company Name&#174;`
5. `Company Name<sup>®</sup>`
6. `Company Name<sup>&reg;</sup>`
7. `Company Name<sup>&#174;</sup>`

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO


Comment: Are the 4007 other questions tagged as SEO in SE off topic as well?

Comment: Yes. Actually they are.

Comment: Haha, that's a problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least [one SEO believes](http://moz.com/community/q/how-do-symbols-affect-seo-for-exact-match-terms) that the search engines will treat the variations all the same. We can see from the a Google search for [Adobe®](https://www.google.com/search?q=adobe%C2%AE) vs. [Adobe](https://www.google.com/search?q=adobe) that the term does not in change the result count.

In most of what I have seen in various keyword tools, search engines like to just assume non-alphanumeric characters are just spaces. My advice would be to just encode the entities (e.g. `&reg;`)

Comment: Great example with the Adobe search! I guess the only difference between your solution and my question is I don't see Adobe using the `&reg;` symbol on their site except for in images.